# Camera names in C# on Windows 8 on Surface

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I'm working on a app for Windows 8. This app relies on the cameras of a device. In particular, i'm very interested in the names of the cameras on a Microsoft Surface. I know that I can get the name of each camera on a device using the DeviceInformation class.

My question is, what are the names of the cameras on a Microsoft Surface? I'm currently developing on an older Dell machine. My device has a camera in the lid. That camera name has "WebCam" in it. I'm trying to learn if I should be looking for "Front" and "Back" or what other possible camera names there are.

Can someone please let me know? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Checking for specific names sounds like a pretty bad idea, doesn't it? Surface isn't the only Windows 8/Windows RT device sold and most likely not the most common one available. You can get device.EnclosureLocation.[Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.panel) if EnclosureLocation is not null and that gives you information on whether the camera is a front or back camera if that information is available.

If you look at the [CameraCaptureControl](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/54997eced4de#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/CameraCaptureControl.cs) in WinRT XAML Toolkit - it has some work done already to enable users to select a front or back camera.